# CkEditor copy/Paste Implementation - copy from editor and copy from outside editor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to paste the same html if i copied from editor as well if i copied from outside editor or any other page which can be with any style while pasting into editor it comes with simple plain text.

But if i copied from my editor whatever element it has with any style like bold, bullet, link , it should be retain with same on pasting it.

For simple plain text : config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;

for html it need to be disable mean false.

But i need both things on the condition if i copy from editor and if i copy from outside editor ...

I need a solution to give this condition on which i can write two different code as per requirement .

Please suggest the logic.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter pasted data which comes from the outside, you can use `pasteFilter`, which does exactly this: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-pasteFilter

The problem is that recognising where the data comes from works fine only in Chrome, right now. In other browsers there is no full support for the Clipboard API. There are tickets to introduce some workaround: (http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12872 for Firefox) and (http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12873 for IE). But for now every paste is treated as an external paste there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question is to apply both content resources 
1. copied and pasted in the same editor (internal), and 
3. coming from all other sources like websites, MS Word, etc. 
(external).
while using internal resources it should retain html (p, h2, span, strong, a,table etc)
while using external it retain simple plain text only
thanks